# Creating multiple locators in Manipulator with constrained motion

Tags: manipulate, locator

I found a code to create multiple controls for a manipulate with a manipulate input and is working perfectly.

```
Manipulate[
 With[{value = Table[c[i], {i, 1, n}], 
   controls = Sequence @@ Table[{c[i], 0, 1}, {i, 1, n}]}, 
  Manipulate[value, controls]], {n, 1, 10, 1}]
```

But what I need is to do the same thing with locators instead of points and the motion of the locators should be constrained to vertical motion at their respective x points. The locator action can be viewed from the following code

```
Manipulate[
 Show[Graphics[{Line[{{0, point[1][[2]]}, {1, point[2][[2]]}, {2, 
       point[3][[2]]}, {3, point[4][[2]]}, {4, point[5][[2]]}}], 
    Locator[{0, point[1][[2]]}], Locator[{1, point[2][[2]]}], 
    Locator[{2, point[3][[2]]}], Locator[{3, point[4][[2]]}], 
    Locator[{4, point[5][[2]]}]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 2}}]], {{point[1], {0, 0}}, Locator, 
  Appearance -> None}, {{point[2], {1, 0}}, Locator, 
  Appearance -> None}, {{point[3], {2, 0}}, Locator, 
  Appearance -> None}, {{point[4], {3, 0}}, Locator, 
  Appearance -> None}, {{point[5], {4, 0}}, Locator, 
  Appearance -> None}]
```

Here, instead of the specified number of locator points, it should be updated on the go. The closest code I got is the following but it gives an error.

```
Manipulate[
 With[{pointlist = Table[{i - 1, point[i][[2]]}, {i, 1, n}], 
   Locatorlist = Table[Locator[{i - 1, point[i][[2]]}], {i, 1, n}],
   controls = 
    Sequence @@ 
     Table[{{point[i], {i - 1, 0}}, Locator, Appearance -> None}, {i, 
       1, n}]},
  Manipulate[{MatrixForm[pointlist], 
    Show[Graphics[{Line[pointlist], Locatorlist}, 
      PlotRange -> {{0, n}, {0, 10}}]]}, controls]], {n, 2, 10, 1}]
```

The error message generated are
1. "Coordinate $CellContext`point[2] should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form."
2. "Part 2 of point[1] does not exist. >>"
Eventhough the error is generated I am able to get the motion constraint and the graph is getting plotted. I cannot use vertical sliders as this has to be plotted on a graph with multiple set of the same.
Can anyone help me, please???

Answer (score 2):

After a few hit and trials, I found the answer to my own question. I had to call the variables in the second Manipulate section. The code is:

```
Manipulate[With[{pointarr = Table[point[i], {i, 1, n}],
   controls = 
    Sequence @@ 
     Table[{{point[i], {i - 1, 0}}, Locator, Appearance -> None}, {i, 
       1, n}]},
  Manipulate[pointlist = Table[{i - 1, pointarr[[i, 2]]}, {i, 1, n}]; 
   Locatorlist = Table[Locator[{i - 1, pointarr[[i, 2]]}], {i, 1, n}];
    Show[Graphics[{Line[pointlist], Locatorlist}, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, n}, {0, 10}}]], controls]], {n, 2, 10, 1}]
```

Its working perfect now. Hope the solution might be useful to someone.
Thanks and Happy new year.